# Django Not implemented work around

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

So [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831510/django-using-annotate-count-and-distinct-on-a-queryset) has been asked before, but there is no answer. I know that joining an annotated queryset with a distinct one is not implemented in Django, but the question is: **what would an alternate way of doing this be?**

## code example:

```
qs1 = Example.objects.filter(...).annotate(...)
qs2 = Example.objects.filter(...).distinct(...)
from itertools import chain
answer = chain(qs1,qs2)
```

but this will return the following error because "it is not implemented" in Django:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.pyc in __iter__(self)
     94                - Responsible for turning the rows into model objects.
     95         """
---> 96         self._fetch_all()
     97         return iter(self._result_cache)
     98

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.pyc in _fetch_all(self)
    852     def _fetch_all(self):
    853         if self._result_cache is None:
--> 854             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
    855         if self._prefetch_related_lookups and not self._prefetch_done:
    856             self._prefetch_related_objects()

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.pyc in iterator(self)
    218             klass_info = get_klass_info(model, max_depth=max_depth,
    219                                         requested=requested, only_load=only_load)
--> 220         for row in compiler.results_iter():
    221             if fill_cache:
    222                 obj, _ = get_cached_row(row, index_start, db, klass_info,

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/sql/compiler.pyc in results_iter(self)
    708         fields = None
    709         has_aggregate_select = bool(self.query.aggregate_select)
--> 710         for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
    711             for row in rows:
    712                 if has_aggregate_select:

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/sql/compiler.pyc in execute_sql(self, result_type)
    769         """
    770         try:
--> 771             sql, params = self.as_sql()
    772             if not sql:
    773                 raise EmptyResultSet

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/sql/compiler.pyc in as_sql(self, with_limits, with_col_aliases)
    119             if distinct_fields:
    120                 raise NotImplementedError(
--> 121                     "annotate() + distinct(fields) not implemented.")
    122             if not ordering:
    123                 ordering = self.connection.ops.force_no_ordering()

NotImplementedError: annotate() + distinct(fields) not implemented.
```

So, again, the question is: **What is some way to accomplish chaining these querysets?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do something like this some time back, so what your doing with iter tools is right, you will have to cast it to list.

```
from itertools import chain

cars = Cars.objects.all()
trucks = Truck.objects.all()
all_vechiles = chain( list(cars), list(trucks) )
```

source here:http://mushfiq.me/2013/08/04/django-merging-to-queryset-using-itertools/

Comment: I still get the same error...note that your example is not using distinct nor annotation, which is what is causing my error. If I take out my `distict(...)`, then this works without using `list`, but I need the distinct call

Comment: That is strange, might be because Django queries are lazy, you might what to try forcing the query evaluation and then chain them

Comment: that works! if you edit your answer I will accept it (just put the `list` function around `cars` and `trucks` rather than the whole chain)