# Django ORM: distinct and annotate

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-models

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
class Developer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name= models.CharField(max_length=255)
    team = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    closed_tickets = models.IntegerField()

    objects = DeveloperManager()
```

I want to write a query which returns:

> Write SQL to show percentage of team tickets closed by every developer and rank developers by contribution level.
> something like this:
> [image]
> is there a way to it in a one query?

I am trying to think in the direction of annotation with distinct clause

```
class DeveloperManager(models.Manager):
    def rank(self):
        return self.order_by('team').annotate(
            total=models.Sum(
                'closed_tickets'
            ),
            piece=models.F('closed_tickets') / models.F('total'),
        ).distinct('team').values()
```

but it returns me an error:

```
NotImplementedError: annotate() + distinct(fields) is not implemented.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of the `NotImplementedError` is

> To let you know that you can't combine annotate and distinct (with
> fields) together at this time, which means that it doesn't work right
> now. (@Chris Pratt says in comments of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11831510/11805525))

Maybe this helps:

```
Developer.objects.raw("""
    select *, rank() over (partition by team order by percentage desc) as rank
    from (
          select *,
                 closed_tickets * 100 / (
                     select sum(closed_tickets) total
                     from t_developer
                     where team = tmp1.team
                     group by team
                 ) percentage
          from t_developer tmp1
    );
""")
```

Comment: you forget `as foo` in the end. Thanks!